# Purpose of using conditional comment <!--[if gte mso 9]>

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone tell me, why the conditional comment  is used?

Will it affect the IE browsers below version 9 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code sandwiched between the opening and closing tags here will only affect Microsoft Outlook 9 or later clients. Note that because it says `mso` rather than `IE`, it does not affect Internet Explorer.

A quick breakdown of Outlook versions:

- Outlook 2000 - Version 9
- Outlook 2002 - Version 10
- Outlook 2003 - Version 11
- Outlook 2007 - Version 12
- Outlook 2010 - Version 14
- Outlook 2013 - Version 15

For a more detailed explanation, you can see this helpful page from [Mailchimp](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/)