# Whats the purpose of the <!--[if !gte mso 9]> conditional comment?

Tags: html, email, html-email

I saw this conditional statement in an email campaign: `<!--[if !gte mso 9]>`

Does `!gte` equals to `lt`?

E.g. Does this statement simply means that it targets mso clients < version 9?

Comment: I believe this may be a duplicate of [Purpose of using conditional comment <!--\[if gte mso 9\]>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123669/purpose-of-using-conditional-comment-if-gte-mso-9); if not, please clarify how your question differs and/or how the answers in this link fail to answer your question.  Thanks, happy coding!

Comment: It doesn't duplicate the mentioned topic. The main question of the mentioned topic is: "Will it affect the IE browsers below version 9 ?".

Comment: Fair point, thanks for clarifying; I've retracted my "close" vote.

Comment: probably. And almost certainly useless. Outlook desktop usually behaves similarly all the way through (there are very edge cases though). But I normally use `[if mso]`